# Optimise queries file information and attributes inside of function called at regular intervals

Tags: c

I'm developing an application that records audio files with GStreamer.
One feature of this app is to display a GTK dialog with a label
that contains information about the file recording process (name, type and size).

code:

```
static int timeout_id = -1;
static GtkWidget *file_label, *type_label, *size_label;

static gboolean timeout_cb(gpointer data)
{
    GFile *session_file;
    GFileInfo *info;

    session_file = g_file_new_for_path (path);
    info = g_file_query_info (session_file,
                  G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_DISPLAY_NAME ","
                  G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_CONTENT_TYPE ","
                  G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_SIZE,
                  G_FILE_QUERY_INFO_NONE,
                  NULL,
                  NULL);
    if (info != NULL) {
            /* name */
            const gchar *display_name = g_file_info_get_attribute_string (info,
                                    G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_DISPLAY_NAME);

            gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (file_label), display_name);

            /* type */
            const gchar *type = g_file_info_get_attribute_string (info,
                                                    G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_CONTENT_TYPE);

            gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (type_label), type);

            /* size */
            guint64 size = g_file_info_get_attribute_uint64 (info,
                               G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_SIZE);
            gchar *tmp = g_format_size_full (size, G_FORMAT_SIZE_LONG_FORMAT);

            gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (size_label), tmp);

            g_free (tmp);

            g_object_unref (info);
    }
    g_object_unref (file);

    return TRUE;
}

void run_status_window(Record *record)
{
    timeout_id = g_timeout_add(500, (GSourceFunc) timeout_cb, record);
}
```

I'm use queries for file information and attributes and calling this at 500 ms intervals.

My question is how can optimise this feature because the name and type aren't likely to change during the recording process.

Thanks

Comment: The name and type aren't likely to change during the recording process, right? Is there some way you can only query the size? Caching the other data between updates is easy enough.